# Is there a way in PHP to upload database from localhost to cloud? MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there a way in PHP to upload database from localhost to cloud with just one click? What I am thinking if it is possible to have a button in my system for localhost (offline system) only. Then the code of it is: if there is a internet connection, the localhost database will update the cloud database. Or anyway for it to do it? TIA.

Comment: What is a "cloud database"? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Do you want some records from your local DB to be written to the remote DB or do you want to completely overwrite (restore) the remote DB with your local one?
"cloud database" I assume is a remote DB hosted with a cloud service provided (AWS, softlayer) etc.

Comment: Yes remote DB, sorry for that. What I want is records from local DB to be written to the remote DB. local DB -> remote DB.

Comment: @RonnelGonzales is your problem solved ?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not expert in that, but I think you can do that. For that you have to first check that you are connected or not by writing php script that checks your connect.

example :

```
<?php
function is_connected()
{
    $connected = @fsockopen("www.example.com", 80); 
                                        //website, port  (try 80 or 443)
    if ($connected){
        $is_conn = true; //action when connected
        fclose($connected);
    }else{
        $is_conn = false; //action in connection failure
    }
    return $is_conn;

}
?>
```

And then you can write your update query with `remote_db` connection details(`DB_user_name, db_password, db_name, etc`) if `connection = true`. And in else part you can update your `local_db`.

And you can call this function `on_click` event.

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: I don't know the update query for the remote db and local db. Can you please show me?

Comment: Your update query is same for both, local_db and remote_db. You have to mention your db credentials correctly to connect to db.